# Error 'git: 'remote-git+https' is not a git command. See 'git --help' when trying to publish atom package

Tags: git, package, atom-editor

I'm trying to run `apm publish minor` in the directory of the new atom package I've created but it doesn't let me and fails with the aforementioned error: `git: 'remote-git+https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` Any ideas?

I've tried updating git, and I just recently updated Atom.

Comment: May you share what the git url in the `package.json` is?

Comment: Matt, we suspect there is an URL like `git+https://` in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I had it saying git+https:// instead of just https:// I would have thought it would have failed at an earlier step, but I guess not.